# ¿Como insertar un dato N cantidad de veces en la misma fila?

Tags: php, mysql

Debo insertar el costo por cuota segun la cantidad de cuotas que tenga el curso EJEMPLO:
DIGA CUANTAS CUOTAS TIENE EL CURSO: 5
VALOR POR CUOTA: 22.000BS.
Ese valor debe guardarse 5 veces en 5 campos distintos c1,c2,c3,c4,c5. Y asi que se guarde cualquier cantidad de veces segun el numero de cuotas.

Comment: Perfecto pudes mostrarnos alguna avances para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, prácticamente esperas que escriban el programa por ti. Te recomiendo que dividas tu proyecto en partes mas pequeñas y manejables y que resuelvas cada parte de una en una. Si enfrentas algún problema, entonces pregunta aquí todo lo que necesites. Si es posible, incluye en cada pregunta un __[mcve]__. Consulta esta guía _[ask]_.

Comment: Luis revertí tu edición, porque no puedes cambiar totalmente el foco de la pregunta, por mas que tengas una respuesta valida, si no la misma quedaría invalida. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, acepta esta y hasla como otra pregunta. Si necesitas aclaraciones hacelas en la respuesta. Si no contesta tu pregunta, mejora la pregunta con toda la informacion que falta. Lo que hiciste vos mismo a tu pregunta se considera vandalismo, salvo que dejes toda la información que ya estaba y hagas las aclaraciones del caso.

Comment: y creo que tener un diseño con n columnas segun la cantidad de cuotas ya es un mal diseño... por ahi tu problema  esta por ese lado..

Comment: Disculpa gbianchi es que recien acabo de ingresar al foro y no se como funciona queria mostrar lo que tengo de codigo asi como lo hizo Gabil pero no supe como. Mil disculpas, y respecto a lo de las columnas si he pensado que no es un buen diseño, pero que me recomendarias si necesito que cada cuota tenga su monto. Ademas tambien lo que pasa es que cada 3 cuotas debe aumentarse el 20% del costo de la cuota anterior. No se si estoy enredado en un vaso de agua, pero no se que hacer. Si podrias ayudarme con una idea como debo plantear mi tabla seria de gran ayuda para mi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente lo que estas intentando hacer es ir generando un string para tu insert que se cree en función a un contador. Siguiendo tu ejemplo un posible código sería:

```
//Num de cuotas  a insertar
$numeroCuotas = 5;

// Asumimos que la conexión a mysql ya está inicializada corréctamente y se almacena en la variable $db

//Variable que almacenará los campos sobre los q hacer le insert
$campos = "";

//Variable para los valores a insertar.
$valores = "";

for($i = 1; $i <= $numeroCuotas; $i++){
    $campos .= 'costo' . $i . ', ';
    $valores .= '\'22000\', ';
}

//Quitamos los carácteres ', ' de los strings
if($campos != ''){
    $campos = substr($campos, 0, -2);
    $valores = substr($valores, 0, -2);
}

//Generamos los inserts
$insert = 'INSERT INTO TABLA (' . $campos . ') VALUES (' . $valores . ');';

//Ejecutamos el insert
$db->query($insert);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Galbi, entiendo lo que planteas, pense en un contador tambien. Pero entiendo hasta despues del for, en la variable $campos .= 'costo' .  $i  . ', '; ese 'costo' es el nombre del campo de la tabla o de donde se lo trae? Dejare algo de lo que llevo para que veas bien:

Comment: function abrir_curso($curso, $horario, $num_cuotas, $costo)
  {
      $query = "INSERT INTO cursos_abiertos(curso,horario)
      VALUES( '$curso', '$horario', '$inscripcion')";
      $sql = $mysqli->query($query);

      $val = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

      $query2 = "INSERT INTO cuotas(id_curso,cantidad)VALUES('$val','$num_cuotas')";
      $sql2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

      $val2 = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

      $campos = "";
      $valores = "";  VENDRIA LO QUE ME PLANTEASTE PERO NO SE COMO HACER POR LO QUE TE DIJE PORQUE EN MI TABLA costo_cuotas tengo 50 campos

Comment: Dentro del `for` lo único que haces es preparar tanto los campos para el _insert_ como los valores. Según me has dicho los campos en tu BD son del estilo de "costo1", "costo2", "costo3" ... Por lo que con el bucle puedes generar la consulta y ejecutarla. `for($i = 1; $i <= $numeroCuotas; $i++){
    $campos .= 'costo' . $i . ', ';
    $valores .= '\'22000\', ';
}
`Si el problema es el insert sobre el resto de campos (hasta los 50 campos que dices q tienes)porque no puedes dejarlos vacíos,  entonces modifica el bucle para que rellene todos los campos.

Comment: Ok ya estoy entendiendo mejor, disculpa mi poco conocimiento es que no tengo mucho tiempo programando o tratando de programar. Yo lo que quiero es que se rellenen tantos campos como yo le diga, si le digo que son 3 cuotas que se rellenen solo costo1, costo2, costo3. y asi cualquier cantidad. el resto no importa que queden vacios. deberia hacerlo asi? for($i = 1; <=$n_cuotas; $i++){ $campos .='costo1' . $i .', ';     $valores .= $costo_cuota; }                                                                         $query = "INSERT INTO monto_cuotas (' . $campos . ')VALUES(' . $valores . ')";

Comment: Si, recuerda quitar la ultima coma de los campos y los valores para que el insert tenga una sintaxis correcta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Galbi por tu ayuda. Una ultima pregunta, en donde quitas lo caracteres alli en el if que hiciste, ese 0, -2 es para que, que funcion cumple?

Comment: La idea es quitar la ultima coma del strin q contiene los campos y los valores para q la sintaxis de la query sea correcta

Comment: Ahora entiendo. Muchas gracias Galbi. Ire a probar..

Comment: Me ha corrido muy bien Galbi, gracias de veras. Ahora como haria si necesito que cada 3 campos me aumente el 10% del monto. ejemplo si son 6 montos que el monto 4, 5, 6 se aumente el 10% del monto pasado, osea que cada 3 registros se aumente el 10% del monto pasado, sea cual sea la cantidad de montos que inserte. No se si esto se podra hacer, o debo buscarle la vuelta de otra forma.

Comment: Si se puede hacer, pero creo q eso ya es una pregunta con el contenido suficiente como para q abras otra pregunta